# Python, element wise sorting of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I am trying to sort each row of a DataFrame element wise.

Input:

```
    A   B   C
0   10  5   6
1   3   6   5
2   1   2   3
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0   10  6   5
1   6   5   3
2   3   2   1
```

It feels this should be easy but I've been failing for  while... Very much a beginner in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) with swap ordering by indexing:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)[:, ::-1], 
                   index=df.index, 
                   columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
    A  B  C
0  10  6  5
1   6  5  3
2   3  2  1
```

Pandas solution, slowier, is apply sorting for each row separately, convert to array and then to `Series`:

```
f = lambda x: pd.Series(x.sort_values(ascending=False).to_numpy(), index=df.columns)
df1 = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df1)
    A  B  C
0  10  6  5
1   6  5  3
2   3  2  1
```

If possible missing values for me working:

```
print (df)
      A    B    C
0  10.0  6.0  5.0
1   5.0  3.0  NaN
2   2.0  1.0  NaN


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)[:, ::-1], 
                   index=df.index, 
                   columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
      A    B    C
0  10.0  6.0  5.0
1   NaN  5.0  3.0
2   NaN  2.0  1.0
```

In pandas is possible use `na_position` parameter for specify order of them:

```
f = lambda x: pd.Series(x.sort_values(ascending=False, na_position='first').to_numpy(), 
                        index=df.columns)
df1 = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df1)
      A    B    C
0  10.0  6.0  5.0
1   NaN  5.0  3.0
2   NaN  2.0  1.0

f = lambda x: pd.Series(x.sort_values(ascending=False, na_position='last').to_numpy(), 
                        index=df.columns)
df1 = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df1)
      A    B    C
0  10.0  6.0  5.0
1   5.0  3.0  NaN
2   2.0  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: I'm very grateful for the response! But it throws up an error: "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'"

Comment: @Tikhon - there is used `.to_numpy()` ?

Comment: Yea my dataframe is called stocks. stocks = pd.DataFrame(stocks.sort(stocks.to_numpy(), axis=1)[:, ::-1], index = stocks.index, columns = stocks.columns)

Comment: @Tikhon - there is typo, `stocks.sort`, need `np.sort`

Comment: Thanks! But error now is: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'

Comment: @Tikhon - there are missing values, unfortunately. If sorting, missing values should be last? Or first?

Comment: @Tikhon - Not so easy, need more time for it.

Comment: I'm VERY grateful.

Comment: @Tikhon - btw, what is your pandas version? I test it with `NaN`s and no error (but missing values was first)

Comment: 1.0.1 but some of my values read "None" and others "nan". Is there a way of making it robust to all non-floats?

Comment: @Tikhon - yes, I think better is all flaots, it means all `NaN`s. Btw, really hard, sorting to last

Comment: to first is just as good - my intention is to filter out extreme values form both ends...

Comment: @Tikhon - For me working if all values are numbers and missing values are `NaN`s

Comment: @Tikhon - Edited answer.

Comment: thanks dude will work on it. If ever you find yourself in Melbourne AU - I owe you a beer.

Comment: @Tikhon - Australia, it is a bit far, but who knows ;)